# Third level Select Drop-down fails to change when first and second drop downs select value changes

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I created 3 select forms whose value should change based on first selection. For example, select country and states in that country is displayed. Select state and cities are displayed. But the reality I find on ground is that when I test this code, states changed when country is changed. But cities fail to populate anything when state is changed. If however I choose to set a default value in state and change it first, cities are generated. But when I start this from country, and then state, city would fail. Below is the code: I don't see what is wrong.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("select.country_id").change(function(){
        var selectedCountry = $(".country_id option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "location_state_processor.php",
            data: { country_id : selectedCountry } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#responsestate").html(data);
        });
    });

    $("select.state_id").change(function(){
        var selectedState = $(".state_id option:selected").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "location_city_processor.php",
            data: { state_id : selectedState } 
        }).done(function(data){
            $("#responsecity").html(data);
        });
    });

});
</script>

<div id="responsecountry">
<select name="country_id" class="country_id select" title="Select Country"><option value="0">Select Country</option><option value="1">Afghanistan</option><option value="2">Albania</option>
<option value="3">Algeria</option>
<option value="4">American Samoa</option>
<option value="5">Andorra</option><option value="6">Angola</option>
<option value="7">Anguilla</option>
<option value="8">Antarctica</option>
</select></div>



<div id="responsestate"><select class="state_id select" name="state_id"> 
       <option value="0">--Select State--</option><option value="5303">Barisal</option><option value="1161">Chittagong</option><option value="1162">Dhaka</option><option value="1163">Khulna</option><option value="1164">Rajshahi</option><option value="5304">Sylhet</option></select></div>




<div id="responsecity"><select class="city_id select" name="city_id"> 
<option value="0">--Select City--</option>
<option value="19081">Ackley</option>
<option value="19082">Ackworth</option>
<option value="18035">Adair</option>
<option value="19131">Adel</option>
</select></div>
```

Comment: Did you verify the `data` you are getting there? Also, can you check if there are any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi @NisargShah how can I do that? Yes, no console error

Comment: You can find some basics here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript

Comment: I bet the second change event isn't executed when you fill it with new data. The change event is called when it's value changes, i.e. when the selected index changes in case of a select tag. Try manually calling `$("select.state_id").change()` at the end of the `$.done()` function in the first change  event.

Comment: @Glubus Isn't the second change event supposed to be triggered when I change the value of state, even though state now has new data generated when country was changed? I have tried what you suggested, all to no avail

Comment: @Ekene Im not sure tbh, hence why I posted it as a comment rather than a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code:

```
<div id="responsestate"><select class="state_id select" name="state_id" onchange="fetchCities(this)">
    <option value="0">--Select State--</option>
    <option value="5303">Barisal</option>
    <option value="1161">
        Chittagong
    </option>
    <option value="1162">Dhaka</option>
    <option value="1163">Khulna</option>
    <option value="1164">Rajshahi</option>
    <option value="5304">Sylhet</option>
</select></div>




function fetchCities(ele){
    state_id = $(ele).val();
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "location_city_processor.php",
            data: { state_id : selectedState };
            success: function(responseData, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                results = responseData.results;
                $("#responsecity").html(data);
            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log(jqXHR, errorThrown);
            }
        });

}
```

Comment: This will work except that generating `onchange="fetchCities(this)"` when state changes will not work

Comment: What do you mean by state changes will not work? Above code suppose to work on change event of select dropdown. It should work anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar kind of problem once.
Though I was using angularjs.
The problem is coming because you are binding the response with html.
you better write this change function in your controller and store the response in some array.
Then iterate the array in your option select in html.
Same will be followed to get cities as well.